# How to download/import json file in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, import

I'm use this command mongoimport `–d zipcode –c code …/zips.json`
for create my database and collection and download json file, but in terminal I got next:

> `Fri Jun 29 22:43:22.294 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
>   or
>   `Fri Jun 29 22:06:29.164 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`
>   Anybody can me explain how to import json file my in mongodb?

Comment: So what does your json file look like?

Comment: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "52b213b38594d8a2be17c780" }, "approvalfy" : 1999, "board_approval_month" : "November", "boardapprovaldate" : "2013-11-12T00:00:00Z", "borrower" : "FEDERAL DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF ETHIOPIA", "closingdate" : "2018-07-07T00:00:00Z", "country_namecode" : "Federal Democratic Republic of Ethiopia!$!ET", "countrycode" : "ET", "countryname" : "Federal Democratic Republic of Ethiopia", "countryshortname" : "Ethiopia", "docty" : "Project Information Document,Indigenous Peoples Plan,Project Information Document", "envassesmentcategorycode" : "C" }

Comment: like this, but he is very long. I reduced him

Comment: Based on the error message, it appears you are trying to run `mongoimport` in the `mongo` shell instead of an operating system shell (`bash`, `cmd`, etc). What O/S are you using?

Comment: I'm using Manjaro Linux